# Get current timezone on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, sed, timezone

On previous version of CentOS, I used the following command to get the current timezone in my bash script:

```
timezone=$(sed 's/ZONE=//g' /etc/sysconfig/clock)
```

Output is 
`"America/New_York"`

How can I achieve an exact output on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS 7 specific:

```
timedatectl | gawk -F': ' ' $1 ~ /Timezone/ {print $2}'
```

And displaying just the timezone:

`timedatectl | gawk -F'[: ]+' ' $2 ~ /Timezone/ {print $3}'`

more generic:

```
date +%Z
```

Comment: Thank you mate...This gives `America/New_York (EST, -0500)` as ouput.Could you modify your first command to make it display only `America/New_York`

Comment: @user2650277: With GNU awk: `timedatectl | awk '/Timezone:/ {print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using `perl`, you can use [DateTime::TimeZone](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm) module from CPAN:

```
$ perl -MDateTime::TimeZone -E '
  say DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => "local")->name();
'
Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
```

POSIXly, you can use [date](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) with `%Z` format:

```
$ date +%Z
ICT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timedatectl | awk '/Time zone:/ {print $3}'
```

Answer (score -1):

For the time zone, you can use geolocation:

```
$ curl https://ipapi.co/timezone
America/Chicago
```

Or:

```
$ curl http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone
America/Chicago
```

http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#Time_zone

Comment: This doesn't seem to jive with the original intent of the question. The locale can be set independent of where the IP of the box resides geo-wise.